# Get a specific value from a table with using a few conditions in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, arcpy

I have a table that each different values in the table is the result of a combination of different conditions.For example in the below image the condition is as follow: if coverType=fallow , Treatment=Crop Residue Cover, Condition/ImperviousArea=Good, SoilType=C  then the value is equal to 83.I want to have a tool which asks the user to choose a value from each column (e.g. choose CoverType; SoilType, ...) and then return the related number as output. Do you have any thoughts how should I do this?
So far I have just the first lines of the code as below:
[image]

```
import arcpy
path= r'H\Python\FinalProject\RunOff.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace= path
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

table=r'H\Python\FinalProject\RunOff.gdb\CN.csv'
cursor= arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
```

Comment: If its ArcPy I think you are better researching/asking at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are restricted to ArcGIS 10.0 or earlier, I suggest using the [da cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm). The syntax is a little easier.

However, you're definitely on the right track. The cursor lets you loop through the table and find a row in which the three categories match the user's input.

```
cover_type = #userinput
treatment = #userinput
condition = #userinput

field_list = ["CoverType", "Treatment", "Condition", "B"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, field_list) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == cover_type and row[1] == treatment and row[2] == condition:
            print row[3]
        else:
            print "no matching combination"
```